# Convert Facebook pixel code in jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, tracking

Has anyone already transformed the [facebook pixel tracking code](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755) into jQuery-functions?

I tried to use it with a [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), and  but afterwards the tracking did not work :(

```
! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s)
{
  if(f.fbq) return;
  n = f.fbq = function()
  {
    n.callMethod ?
    n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
  };
  if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
  n.push = n;
  n.loaded = !0;
  n.version = '2.0';
  n.queue = [];
  t = b.createElement(e);
  t.src = v;
  s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
}(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/fbevents.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

untested... :)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
function($)
{
  if(! window.fbq)
  {
    n = window.fbq = function ()
    {
      n.callMethod ?
      n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };

    if (!window._fbq) window._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];

    $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/fbevents.js', 
    function()
    {
      console.log('facebook pixel loaded... do your thing');
    });
  }
});
</script>
```